# Why $f$ may not be continuous despite $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(0,0)=0$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let a function $f :R^2\to R $ so that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(0,0)=0$ then $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$. Why is this statement false? I thought the existance of a limit at a point **a** implied the continuity at that point.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing that $f(0,0)$ may be different from $0$.